# Override Django ImageField validation

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to create a form where users will be allowed to upload any image file + SWF files. Django's ImageField does not support SWF so I need to override it.

What I want to do is to check if the file is SWF, if True, return it. If it's not SWF, call the original method which will take care of the file validation.

However, I am not sure how to implement that. Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve, but it does not work:

```
from hexagonit import swfheader    


class SwfImageField(forms.ImageField):

    def to_python(self, data):
        try:
            swfheader.parse(data)
            return data
        except:
            return super(SwfImageField, self).to_python(data)
```

What is actually does is allowing **only** SWF files at the moment.

Comment: Why don't you use `FileField` with a custom validator?

Comment: Is there a way to modify my code and achieve the same result? I thought it was easier to add one extra validation to the existing solution for images.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43770185

Answer (score 1):

An alternative and possibly easiest solution is to use a standard [`FileField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#filefield) with a custom validator:

```
def my_validate(value):
    ext = os.path.splitext(value.name)[1]  # [0] returns path filename
    valid = ['.jpg', '.swf']
    if ext not in valid:
        raise ValidationError("Unsupported file extension.")

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField(validators=[my_validate])
```

Comment: But this only checks for extensions. The ImageField's method uses PIL to check if the file is an actual image.

Answer (score 0):

may be it will be useful:

```
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator


class MyModel(models.Model):
    ......
    my_field = models.FileField('Name', validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['svg', 'jpg', 'png', '.....'])])
```