# Adding validation error message to class-based view (CreateView)

Tags: django, django-models, django-class-based-views

In models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_pics', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

I want to add a ValidationError Message to 'image' field:

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content', 'image']


    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

If user uploads something else in image field the form won't submit, which is fine, but I would like to add extra message something like "Images only..". Ideally combine multiple errors (size or resolution).

I would like to keep the structure of view as class based, so without going into forms.py or making a function based view.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked into using a `FileField` with a custom validator? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30643790/9225671) for ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the validators into your model declaration?, for example:

```
    from .validators import validate_image_filesize, validate_image_size, validate_image_name, validate_file_extension
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_pics', blank=True,
                              validators=[validate_image_filesize,
                                          validate_image_size,
                                          validate_image_name,
                                          validate_file_extension])
```

Define them in your `validators.py` file, for example:

```
def validate_file_extension(value):
    extension = os.path.splitext(value.name)[1]
    valid_extensions = ['.jpg', ]
    if not extension.lower() in valid_extensions:
        raise ValidationError(u'Format is not supported, '
                              u'allowed formats: {}'.format(', '.join(valid_extensions)))
```

Let me know if it works!,

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I implemented your proposed solution, the behaviour of the html handling the form is the same. I'm not entirely sure if I need to "catch" these ValidationErrors in the template or should they just pop up like all other error messages in django (meaning without any user intervention).

Comment: Make sure you are displaying field errors in your template. This [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems no validators or raisingerror were needed after all, Thank You Cheche for your suggestion to display additional error tag in the template, so the solution is quite simple:

in post_form.html:

.... right below the {{ form }}

```
{% if form.image.errors %}
  <div class="alert alert-info">
     {{ form.image.errors }}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```